# Can't pass value of parameter into findOneBy Symfony repository

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence

I am using Symfony (version 2.5.0-DEV) and the doctrine mongodb cookbook on http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html.

I am stuck at the moment trying to pass the value of a defined parameter into findOneByIndex.

So if I do the following `$script = $repository->findOneByIndex(1);` it works perfectly.
But if I do the following `$script = $repository->findOneByIndex($user);` it fails to search with the value of user.

In routing.yml, I have this `pattern:  platform/designing/users/{user}/showuser` and in the controller I simply do this under the showuserAction:

```
$repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('MyMpBundle:Scripts');
$script = $repository->findOneByIndex($user);
```

Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 2):

In your last code example, what is the type of the `$user` variable? I assume it may be a string if it's a routing parameter and coming from the URI. You can use `var_dump()` to get the type and value in one shot.

Based on an earlier comment, you said that the Scripts document had the following fields:

- _id
- name (string)
- description (string)
- index (integer)
- user_id (integer)

If the `index` field in your MongoDB document is an integer, you will need to use an integer in the query. For instance, the `findOneByIndex('1')` will not match a document with integer `1` in its field. A best practice here is to [cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) your values to the appropriate type before querying. It may also be best to stop relying on the magic DocumentRepository methods and explicitly define your own `findBy` methods, which do the casting internally. Then, your controller can pass a numeric string directly from a routing or request parameter and not have to worry about doing the integer cast on its own.

Also, to comment on your original code example:

```
$script = $repository->findOneByIndex($user);
```

This was for the routing pattern `platform/designing/users/{user}/showuser`. You said that this failed to find a result. I assume the `$user` argument to your controller is a user ID. If that is the case, why were you querying on the `index` field instead of `user_id`?

Answer (score 1):

This value should be an integer, not object. Please pass the id, or index value - I don't know how it's stored in mongodb.

```
$repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('MyMpBundle:Scripts');
$script = $repository->findOneByIndex($user->getId());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Index is an integer value. I used your command and got: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getId()

Comment: Which property is an index for your entity?

Comment: sorry I don't get your question well. Perhaps I can state the fields or columns I have (MongoDB): _id, name, description, index, user_id. index and user_id are integers but _id cannot be edited (auto generated)

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass `$user` to `showuser` action? like this (notice $user as parameter):

```
    public function showuserAction($user)
    {
        $repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('MyMpBundle:Scripts');
        $script = $repository->findOneByIndex($user);
    }
```

PS. I'd recommend you to change var `$user` to `$userId` just not to mistake it with $user object

Comment: Yes I passed user in showuser action under routing:   pattern:  metaplatform/designing/users/{user}/showuserjson. and in the controller like:  public function showuserAction($user). I can also see the value of user in echo on the page. But I cannot pass it in the find.

Comment: I have also changed the var $user to $userId but I am getting same result.